# What is the use for `program_id` in program's entrypoint

Tags: cpi, program, instructions, sysvar

All Solana programs receive its own `program_id` as a parameter.
But I don't see how this is useful, as you can use `declare_id` to declare it in case you need it.

I've also seen that if you get your instruction by using `solana_program::sysvar::instructions::get_instruction_relative(0, &instruction_sysvar_account_info)`, the `program_id` would be not of our program, but of the program, which called our program (also, what will happen if the instruction wasn't called through CPI?). Are those somehow related?

Here is an exert HelloWorld [example](https://github.com/solana-labs/example-helloworld/blob/master/src/program-rust/src/lib.rs).

```
// Declare and export the program's entrypoint
entrypoint!(process_instruction);

// Program entrypoint's implementation
pub fn process_instruction(
    program_id: &Pubkey, // Public key of the account the hello world program was loaded into
    accounts: &[AccountInfo], // The account to say hello to
    _instruction_data: &[u8], // Ignored, all helloworld instructions are hellos
) -> ProgramResult {
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Using the actual `program_id` is more robust to errors.
If you declare *the expected* `program_id`, you have to keep track on it. (Like, for some reason you've chosen to deploy a new version to a new address).

If the address is changed, your program with `declare_id!` may exhibit strange behavior with cryptic errors. It can reject accounts, owned by itself (because it will compare `owner` with the wrong `program_id`), fail to write to supposedly correct accounts (again, because the program will assume, that it is the owner of the account, but runtime will reject such writes).

Answer (score 5):

I can think of two ways it's useful depending on whether the address where your program is currently running is somehow important:

**The running address is important**: receiving `program_id` allows you to compare the *expected* address (`declare_id!`) with the address where the program is *actually* running and change behaviour if necessary.

**The running address is *not* important**: having access to `program_id` saves you 32 bytes of storage fees while still being able to do things like manipulate program-derived addresses.

```
$ solana rent -u m 32
Rent per byte-year: 0.00000348 SOL
Rent per epoch: 0.000003048 SOL
Rent-exempt minimum: 0.0011136 SOL
```

At the spot price when I'm writing this of $45.12/SOL that savings means the program would cost about 5¢ less to deploy using the rent-exempt minimum.  Yay!