# What is the point of `declare_id`?

Tags: program, entrypoint

This question is the converse of [What is the use for `program_id` in program's entrypoint](https://solana.stackexchange.com/q/1220/234).

What is the point of `declare_id!()`, because the `program_id` is passed as an argument to the the entrypoint?

Answer (score 3):

`declare_id!()` is a macro to define a **static** public key. We often need to use static public key. (For example, for defining system programs like stake_instructions). In those cases, we can not define static public key directly from the string. (Try to define static pubkey from string using Pubkey::from_str. It will throw an error). We can build static public key from u8 array using Pubkey::new_from_array but that is not readable. Thus **declare_id** is used for defining **static** public keys for those cases.